# Why is Reference to Base Class ambiguous with :: -operator through derived class?

Tags: c++

So I was wondering why the following code snippet of the diamond problem is not able to be compiled. 
I am aware that this problem is usually solved by virtual inheritance, i didn't use this on purpose. The code is just to showcase my question on why the compiler calls this ambiguous: 
So i have two member variables declared in struct Base, because the two subclasses (in this case structs) do not inherit virtually, i would have a reference to the Base members in each derived struct. Now I have another struct AllDer which would run in the problem of knowing id_ and name_ two times. 
However when i explicitly target id_ and name_ from Base, i don't understand why this would be ambiguous since the direct target variable is specified through the ::-operator.

```
cout << Der1::Base::id_ << Der1::Base::name_ << '\n';
```

Can somebody tell me, why the compiler runs into a problem here? (Please forgive possibly wrong technical terms)
Compiler error message says: "ambiguous conversion from derived class 'AllDer' to base class". Using MinGW 7.3.0 64-bit for C++ in QT Creator.

EDIT: Since this problem seems to get handled differently by compilers, please check the linked question.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using std::string; using std::cout;

struct Base
{
    int id_;
    string name_; //target members for readAllDer() in AllDer

    void read()
    {
        cout << id_ << ' ' << name_ << '\n';
    }
};


struct Der1 : public  Base
{
    //Der1 has own reference to id_, name_
    void readDer1()
    {
        cout << id_ << name_ << '\n';
    }
};

struct Der2 : public  Base
{
    //Der2 has own reference to id_, name_
    void readDer2()
    {
        cout << id_ << name_ << '\n';
    }
};

//
struct AllDer : public Der1, public Der2
{

    void readAllDer()
    {
        cout << Der1::Base::id_ << Der1::Base::name_ << '\n'; // Why is this ambiguous? 
    }
};
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message in the question

Comment: It works without `Base::`, hmm.

Comment: Works on my machine, can you show us a use case?

Comment: @Michael OP also misses to include the error, but now I am also curious on which compiler you do not get an errror

Comment: Microsoft CL (Visual studio 2019) @idclev463035818

Comment: @Michael interesting, gcc and clang produce an error. Now its up to OP to clarify

Answer (score 1):

`Der1::Base` and `Der2::Base` are the same class and `AllDer` derives from it twice. Your method compiles when you pick the members not from `Base` but from `Der1`:

```
struct AllDer : public Der1, public Der2
{

    void readAllDer()
    {
        cout << Der1::id_ << Der1::name_ << '\n'; 
    }
};
```

Comment: This is not a virtual inheritance. I believe you are wrong.

Comment: @Micheal I dont understand what you say. There is no virtual inheritance in OPs code and I dont refer to virtual inheritance. If there was virtual inheritance then `AllDer` would only contain a single `Base` subobject and there would be no ambiguity

Comment: `Der1::Base` and `Der2::Base` are not the same object. They are two distinct objects of the same type. 
You can verify it by setting `Der1::Base::name_` to "A" and `Der2::Base::name_` to "B".

Comment: @Michael `Der1::Base` and `Der2::Base` aren't objects but types

Comment: Of course, I meant that in the context of writing `Der1::Base::name_` and `Der2::Base::name_`, you refer to the field `name_` of two distinct objects.

Comment: @Michael no, they are both refering to `Base`, the same type. Anyhow, I am considering to delete the answer because the question needs to be clarified but I think I'll just leave it

Comment: I added constructors,
```cpp
    AllDer() : 
        Der1("Michael", 1),
        Der2("Daniel", 2)
    {}
```

And now 
```cpp
        cout << Der1::Base::id_ << Der1::Base::name_ << '\n'; // Why is this ambiguous? 
        cout << Der2::Base::id_ << Der2::Base::name_ << '\n'; // Why is this ambiguous? 
```

Prints whta I expect, "1Michael\n2Daniel\n"

Comment: I strongly believe this is a gcc bug, I'll check on clang

Comment: @Michael I believe you that it works on msvc, but I believe that gcc and clang are right here. Otherwise there would be no problem with the diamond

Comment: @Michael opened a new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61477009/is-derived1base-and-derived2base-refering-to-the-same-type

Comment: I understand why you can achieve accessing the Base members trough the directly derived classes. However my question is, why the compiler says Der1::Base:: ... is ambiguous since the access on the Base members should be clear as far as i understand.

Comment: @SörenHepp because `Der1::Base` is not an object, its a type and it is the same type as `Der2::Base`. I opened a new question, because I have my doubts (link above)

Answer (score 0):

Its a classic diamond problem, even if you are saying you are specifying the direct target variable through scope(::)
Here 'Der1' already has copy of 'id_,name_' and you are still trying to access base's copy which is ambiguous for 'AllDer' as its coming by two ways Der1 and Der2.

instead of this:

```
Der1::Base::id_
```

try this:

```
Der1::id_ and Der1::name_
```

hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

you need to inherit Der1 and Der2 virtually from base class like this

```
struct Der1 : virtual public  Base


struct Der2 : virtual public  Base
```

in this [LINK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) said: 
Virtual inheritance is a C++ technique that ensures only one copy of a base class's member variables are inherited by grandchild

Comment: OP is well aware of the double inheritance of `Base`, that's why he's trying to disambiguate `_id` member.

Comment: i don't understand why this answer is wrong but thanks for your comment @Yksisarvinen

Comment: @Yksisarvinen i will be thanks full if you explain why

Comment: I'm not the one who downvoted it, but OP specifically doesn't want virtual inheritance ("*I am aware that this problem is usually solved by virtual inheritance, i didn't use this on purpose.*"). The question is "why `Der1::Base::_id` is ambiguous?"